# Showing Error Wile importing images from assets folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I am using Vite-react-app and importing images from assets folder terminal and webpack throwing errors like Below..

[image]

[image]

[image]

assets Folder path

> H:\My Projects\my-portfolio\src\assets

I am looking for Solution and thank you for any help you may provide

Comment: Pls don’t post images of code. Pls read: [Why shouldn’t I post images of code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,for%20users%20with%20visual%20impairments.)

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong syntax. Please check what dots in path means.

That you have is `import profile from '../assets/logo.svg'` which is looking for folder `assets` inside `src/Components/About`

> One dot (.) always refers to the current folder. Two dots (..) refers to the folder that is one level higher than the current folder. (../../folder) means two level higher than current folder and so on.

In your case you can simply write `import profile from 'assets/logo.svg'`, because is inside of your `src` folder